# What kind of distribution is this and what's on average?

Tags: statistics

A call has a probability of $0.4$ to be answered. Let $Y$ be the number of phone calls made until a call is answered for the first time.

Part 1:

> a) What kind of distribution does $Y$ have? Indicate the name and the parameters.
>
> b) How many calls have to be made on average until the first answer?

Part 2:

> a) What is the probability that $10$ calls will be made until $3$ are answered? Define a random variable $R$ to be the number of calls made until the caller gets $3$ answered and identify the distribution of $R$.
>
> b) What is the average number of unanswered calls until the caller gets $3$ answered?

My try at it:

a) $Y$ is binomial with $p=0.4$, $n = $ number of calls?

b) $u = np = n*0.4$. I'm lost here.

Comment: This wouldn't be a binomial distribution, this is a [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution).

Comment: Also, I made some pretty extensive edits to clean the question up; if I accidentally changed anything meaningful, go ahead and fix it or let me know.

Comment: It seems to be find but I'm not sure why it's a poisson distribution. Guess I'll have to read up more. i thought if given a probability and not an average it'd be binomial.